# What does the big-O notation mean?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plain English explanation of Big O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

I need to figure out `O(n)` of the following:

```
f(n) = 10n^2 + 10n + 20
```

All I can come up with is `50`, and I am just too embarrassed to state how I came up with that.

Can someone explain what it means and how I should calculate it for `f(n)` above?

Comment: You are miunsrstanding the nature of the question when asked what is O(n) - have a read up on Big O notation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: The problem probably lies in that `10n2` should be `10n^2`.

Comment: @glowcoder - I don't think that's the whole problem.

Comment: The question is _far_ too broad in scope: you are asking us to teach you something which should be learned over a period of several lectures and assignments. Perhaps go back to the teacher who set you the homework -- did he/she not also spend four hours explaining algorithmic complexity analysis in great detail beforehand?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal He did which is why I am not going to him.

Comment: @Java: Time for a new school! Or perhaps just begin with a book.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I was joking, someone edited my question to say I have this homework, its not homework, i am going through some lecture slides for my lecture on Monday and one of the questions is this. Could not understand it so thought i would ask here.

Comment: @Java: Why not wait until the professor explains it to you in the lecture? Rather than asking us to attempt to kludge out the entire topic in text?

Comment: @yoda: Please don't make assumptions like that.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal `f(n)=something, then O(n)=?` (see first rev) sounds very much like a copy-paste from an assignment. I merely improved the bad shape the post came in. Also, I don't understand how that word would change the meaning of the post or the answer provided...

Comment: @yoda: A problem that is designed to be posed as a homework assignment isn't necessarily always solved _as_ a homework assignment ;) And the word "homework" has _significant_ connotations in the sorts of answers that result, on SO, due to anti-spoonfeeding policy.

Answer (score 5):

Big-O notation is to do with complexity analysis. A function is `O(g(n))` if (for all except some `n` values) it is upper-bounded by some constant multiple of `g(n)` as `n` tends to infinity. More formally:

`f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` iff there exist constants `n0` and `c` such that for all `n >= n0`, `f(n) <= c.g(n)`

In this case, `f(n) = 10n^2 + 10n + 20`, so `f(n)` is in `O(n^2)`, `O(n^3)`, `O(n^4)`, etc. The *tightest* upper bound is `O(n^2)`.

In layman's terms, what this means is that `f(n)` grows no worse than quadratically as `n` tends to infinity.

There's a corresponding Big-Omega notation which can be used to lower-bound functions in a similar manner. In this case, `f(n)` is also `Omega(n^2)`: that is, it grows no better than quadratically as `n` tends to infinity.

Finally, there's a `Big-Theta` notation which combines the two, i.e. iff `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` and `f(n)` is in `Omega(g(n))` then `f(n)` is in `Theta(g(n))`. In this case, `f(n)` is in `Theta(n^2)`: that is, it grows exactly quadratically as `n` tends to infinity.

--> The point of all this is that as `n` gets big, the linear (`10n`) and constant (`20`) terms become essentially irrelevant, as the value of the function is far more affected by the quadratic term. <--

Comment: What do you mean by "for all except potentially a few n values"? n0 can be in the trillions

Comment: @Brian: Agreed, bad choice of words :)

Comment: @Brian: trillions is "a few values". Yes, my Master's degree is in mathematics, why do you ask? ;-)